# LSTM Plot Scale is Off by Orders of Magnitude

Tags: python, matplotlib, lstm

I’ve been wrangling with an LSTM for stock prediction for the past week. I am at the point where I need to plot the predicted stock price against the actual stock price. However, the plot I generate shows the actual price being 3 orders of magnitude higher than actual value.

I suspect that somehow, I am grabbing the daily volume and not the closing price. I need assistance tracking down the source of the issue.

[image: The offending plot]

Here is the df for the stock data. Note that the opening 'O' and closing price 'C' have been moved to the last two columns.

[image: Dataframe]

```
# Plot the actual vs. predicted stock prices 

    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6)) 

    plt.plot(scaler_Y.inverse_transform(dataframe[['c']]), label='Actual Prices', color='blue') 

    trainPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataframe[['c']]) 

    trainPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan 

    trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict 

    plt.plot(trainPredictPlot, label='Train Predictions', color='red') 

 

    testPredictPlot = np.empty_like(dataframe[['c']]) 

    testPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan 

    testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1+len(testPredict), :] = testPredict[:len(testPredictPlot)-(len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1), :] 

    plt.plot(testPredictPlot, label='Test Predictions', color='green') 

    plt.title(f'LSTM Predictions vs Actual Prices for {symbol}') 

    plt.xlabel('Days') 

    plt.ylabel('Price') 

    plt.legend() 

    plt.grid(True) 

    plt.show()
```

**The full code:**

```
import requests 

import tensorflow as tf 

import pandas as pd 

from datetime import datetime 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import numpy as np 

from tensorflow import keras 

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error 

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM 

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 

from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch          # This might be the wrong tuner keras_tuner.tuners 

 

desktop_path = 'B:/OneDrive/Desktop' 

file_path = f'{desktop_path}/key.txt' 

 

# Read API key from the 'key.txt' file 

with open(file_path, 'r') as file: 

    API_KEY = file.read().strip() 

 

BASE_URL = 'https://api.polygon.io' 

 

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store the results 

results = {} 

 

with open('stocks.txt', 'r') as file: 

    symbols = [line.strip() for line in file] 

 

start_date = '2018-01-01' 

end_date = '2023-10-31' 

interval = '1'  # 1 day 

 

# Loop through each symbol and retrieve data 

 

for symbol in symbols: 

    # Construct the full URL with API key and date parameters 

    endpoint = f'/v2/aggs/ticker/{symbol}/range/{interval}/day/{start_date}/{end_date}' 

    url = f'{BASE_URL}{endpoint}?apiKey={API_KEY}' 

 

    try: 

        # Send a GET request to the API 

        response = requests.get(url) 

 

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 200) 

        if response.status_code == 200: 

            # Parse the JSON response 

            data = response.json() 

 

            # Convert 't' to DataFrame for easier manipulation and set it as the DataFrame index 

            df = pd.DataFrame(data['results'])             

            df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], unit='ms') 

            df.set_index('t', inplace=True) #Setting to the True method modifies the original df directly instead of returning a new df 

            #df['symbol'] = symbol 

            df['20DMA'] = df['c'].rolling(window=20).mean() 

            df['20DSTD'] = df['c'].rolling(window=20).std() 

            df['UpperBand'] = df['20DMA'] + (df['20DSTD'] * 2) 

            df['LowerBand'] = df['20DMA'] - (df['20DSTD'] * 2) 

            results[symbol] = df 

            #print(df.head(df.to_string)) 

            #print(df.to_string(index=True)) 

             

            # REmove the first 20 rows and print the reults. 

            # This is intended to remove the NaN for the 20DMA 

            # However, this does not address the problem with predictions coming out as NaN 

            #df = df.iloc[20:] 

            #for start in range(0, len(df), 100):  # Adjust chunk size as needed 

            #    print(df[start:start+100].to_string()) 

            #    input("Press Enter to continue...")  # Pause between chunks 

 

        else: 

            print(f"Error for symbol {symbol}: {response.status_code} - {response.text}") 

 

    except Exception as e: 

        print(f"An error occurred for symbol {symbol}: {e}") 

         

    columns = list(df.columns) 

    columns.remove('o') 

    columns.remove('c') 

    columns += ['o', 'c']     

    df = df[columns] # Now 'o' and 'c' are the last columns in the DataFrame 

    #print(df.head(10)) 

 

    #Remove the first 20 rows of the df which contain NaN for calculated fields 

    #df = df.iloc[20:] 

 

for index, column in enumerate(df.columns): 

        column_type = df[column].dtype 

        print(f"Column {index}: {column}, Type: {column_type}") 

         

pd.set_option('display.max.columns', None) 

print(df) 


look_back = 3 

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1): 

    dataX, dataY = [], [] 

    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1): 

        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]       # ', :]' means that all features are included ?! 

        dataX.append(a) 

        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 9])  # Assuming 'c' is at index 10 - Dependent variable 

    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY) 


# Loop through each symbol and retrieve data 

for symbol, dataframe in results.items(): 

     

    X = df[['v', 'vw', 'h', 'l', 'n', '20DMA', '20DSTD', 'UpperBand', 'LowerBand', 'o']].values # I removed 'c' 

    Y = df['c'].values 

 

    # Handle NaN values (forward fill for simplicity, choose based on your data) 

    df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True) 

    df.dropna(inplace=True) 

     

 

     

     

    #object.fill(method='ffill', inplace=True) 

    #object.drop(inplace=True) 

 

    scaler_X = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1)) 

    scaler_Y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1)) 

 

    X_scaled = scaler_X.fit_transform(X) 

    Y_scaled = scaler_Y.fit_transform(Y.reshape(-1, 1)) 

 

    # Use the reshaped X_scaled and Y_scaled 

    train_size = int(len(X_scaled) * 0.67) 

    test_size = len(X_scaled) - train_size 

    trainX, trainY = X_scaled[:train_size], Y_scaled[:train_size] 

    testX, testY = X_scaled[train_size:], Y_scaled[train_size:] 

     

 

    trainX, trainY = create_dataset(trainX, look_back) 

    testX, testY = create_dataset(testX, look_back) 

     

    #print(trainX) 

 

 

    # Reshape trainX and testX 

    trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], len(X[0]))) 

    testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], len(X[0]))) 

 

 

# %% 

model = Sequential()  

model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(look_back, len(X[0])), return_sequences=True)) 

model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(look_back, len(X[0])))) 

model.add(Dense(1)) 

model.summary() 

     

 

# %% 

learning_rate = 0.001 

adam_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate) 

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=adam_optimizer) 

 

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=2, validation_data=(testX, testY)) 

 

trainPredict = model.predict(trainX) 

testPredict = model.predict(testX) 

 

# Plot the training and validation loss 

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5)) 

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss') 

plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss') 

plt.title('Model Loss') 

plt.ylabel('Loss') 

plt.xlabel('Epoch') 

plt.legend() 

plt.grid(True) 

plt.show() 

 

 

# %% 

trainPredict = scaler_Y.inverse_transform(trainPredict) 

trainY_inverse = scaler_Y.inverse_transform(trainY.reshape(-1, 1))  # Reshape trainY here 

     

testPredict = scaler_Y.inverse_transform(testPredict) 

testY_inverse = scaler_Y.inverse_transform(testY.reshape(-1, 1))  # Reshape testY here 

 

# %% 

# Handle NaN values in predictions 

trainPredict = np.nan_to_num(trainPredict, nan=0.0) 

testPredict = np.nan_to_num(testPredict, nan=0.0) 

 

# Now you can calculate RMSE 

trainScore = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY_inverse, trainPredict[:,0])) 

print(f'{symbol} Train Score: {trainScore:.2f} RMSE') 

testScore = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY_inverse, testPredict[:,0])) 

print(f'{symbol} Test Score: {testScore:.2f} RMSE') 

 

# %% 

# Plot the actual vs. predicted stock prices 

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6)) 

 

# Plot actual prices 

actual_prices = scaler_Y.inverse_transform(df[['c']])  # Ensure this is closing price data 

plt.plot(actual_prices, label='Actual Prices', color='blue') 

 

# Prepare train predictions for plotting 

trainPredictPlot = np.empty_like(df[['c']]) 

trainPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan 

trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict 

 

# Prepare test predictions for plotting 

# Adjust the index where test predictions start 

testPredictPlot = np.empty_like(df[['c']]) 

testPredictPlot[:, :] = np.nan 

 

# Assuming `testPredict` starts right after `trainPredict` 

testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1+len(testPredict), :] = testPredict 

 

# Plot predictions 

plt.plot(trainPredictPlot, label='Train Predictions', color='red') 

plt.plot(testPredictPlot, label='Test Predictions', color='green') 

 

# Add labels, title, and legend 

plt.title('Stock Price Prediction') 

plt.xlabel('Time') 

plt.ylabel('Price') 

plt.legend() 

plt.grid(True) 

plt.show()
```

I suspect the issue is with the inverse_transform function which is supposed to grab the closing price 'c' from the df. Somehow it isn't grabbing the correct column.